# Why I am getting 'cat: write error: Input/output error' when using cat on a 3-byte-file

Tags: bash, cat

I have a file of 3 bytes. I cannot use cat to see its content.

It happens on Ubuntu-18.04, and also on Windows' WSL - ubuntu (on different machines) 
When using `vi myfile` I see only the letter `q`.
When using `cat -A myfile` I get `M-AM-1$`
When using `hexdump myfile` I get :

```
0000000 b1c1 000a
0000003
```

When using `ls -la myfile` I get `-rw------- 1 iftah iftah 3 Mar 26 11:56 myfile`

And my problem is with: `cat myfile` which returns:

```
cat: write error: Input/output error
```

Why? What is so special about this one?

Comment: Maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327658/i-edited-a-linux-file-with-a-windows-program-while-using-the-windows-subsystem-f is of interest?

Comment: @BrianAgnew thanks, that's it. I tried creating the same file from scratch using `echo -n -e '\xc1\xb1\x0a' > newFile` and in WSL `cat newFile` gives me the same failure while on a dedicated Ubuntu machine, `cat newFile` is successful.

Comment: A *write* error isn't a problem reading the file you passed `cat` as input at all. Just as the name implies, it's a problem encountered *writing* that content to `cat`'s stdout.